# Local branch shown ahead of remote branch after rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase

Every time I rebase my local branch, `git status` shows something like this:

```
# On branch --blah--
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/--blah--' by 11 commits.
```

Only after I push to the branch (which doesn't push anything actually) it says `Everything up-to-date`.

This is strange behavior, and I suspect there is something fundamental that I'm missing. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

What `git rebase origin/branch` does is to put your work on top of the `origin/branch` branch in your local copy.

when you have:

```
local_branch: 1--2--3--4--1'--2'--3'
remote_branch: 1--2--3--4--a--b--c
```

then by issuing `git rebase remote_branch` you end up with

```
local_branch: 1--2--3--4--a--b--c--1'--2'--3'
remote_branch: 1--2--3--4--a--b--c
```

which means that currently your local_branch is indeed some commits ahead of the remote that you rebased on.

after that a `git push` will result in

```
local_branch: 1--2--3--4--a--b--c--1'--2'--3'
remote_branch: 1--2--3--4--a--b--c--1'--2'--3'
```

so your local will then be *up to date*

Check out the [git-rebase doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: I see your point, under this circumstance it is ok. The thing is, there aren't any local changes over the code. In other words;

`local_branch: a-b-c`
`remote_branch: a-b-c-d-e`

after issuing the command I end up with

`local_branch: a-b-c-d-e`
`remote_branch: a-b-c-d-e`

git makes this weird behavior exactly at this state. After issuing a push command, nothing is pushed, but I see the quirk is gone.